# Migrating Customers Magento 1.9 to 2.3.5

Tags: magento2

Migrating Customers Magento 1.9 to 2.3.5
I am trying to migrate all my Magento 1.9 customers (and maybe orders/invoice history as well. Products not needed to transfer) to new Magento 2.3.5 site. I thought I could easily export a.csv file to import to M2, boy was I wrong. I need to find the easiest way to so. Hopefully I don't have to purchase an extension for this.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Team has developed the **Magento 2 Data Migration Tool** to help you efficiently move all of your products, customers, and order data, store configurations, promotions and more to Magento 2. Please refer the [Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/bk-migration-guide.html) which provides information on the tool and best practices for using it to migrate your data.